# Counting Problem - discrete math

Tags: discrete-mathematics, permutations, combinations

I need help with the following problem:

There are three computers A, B, and C. Computer A has 10 tasks, Computer B has 15 tasks, and Computer C has 20 tasks. Each computer must complete its own tasks in order. After, each computer sends its output to a shared fourth computer. How many different orders can the outputs arrive at the fourth computer.

My work so far:
This is a permutation problem since the order matters. 10! * 15! * 20! is what I believe the answer is but I am unsure.

Answer (score 1):

HINT: This is **not** a permutation problem, because the order of tasks for each of the three computers is fixed; the only thing that varies is how the tasks for the three computers are interleaved. Once we know which $10$ of the $10+15+20=45$ positions in the output are occupied by A’s tasks, we know which of A’s tasks is in each of those $10$ positions: they must have been done in order. Similarly, once we know which $15$ positions have the output of B’s tasks, we know which of B’s tasks is in each of those positions.

- How many ways are there to choose the $10$ positions in the output for A’s tasks?
- Once that’s been done, how many ways are there to choose $15$ of the remaining positions for B’s tasks?

At that point all $20$ of the positions that still remain must be filled with C’s tasks in their proper order, so there are no more choices to be made. Putting the pieces together, how many different orders are there in which the $45$ outputs can arrive at the fourth computer?

Comment: Okay, so then wouldn't it be C(45, 10) * C(35, 15) * 1 ? This would account for the combinations of each task for each computer running

Comment: @BrockMarshal: Yes, that’s right.